# Flutter, how to copy text after pressing the button?

Tags: user-interface, button, flutter, dart, copy

For beginning i am really sorry for my not perfect English ;)

I want to create a button that will copy the text value when this button is pressed. I was looking for it but I found no information. How can I create automatic copying in flutter framework?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean but maybe try Clipboard https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/Clipboard-class.html

Comment: Thank you, that is exacly what I mean.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter (Dart) How to add copy to clipboard on tap to a app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55885433/flutter-dart-how-to-add-copy-to-clipboard-on-tap-to-a-app)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First, assign a name to your `String`:

```
String quote = "This is a very awesome quote";
```

Second, copy the `String` to the clipboard :

```
onPressed: (){
    Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: quote));
},
```

To notify the user that it's done you could use a `SnackBar`:

```
onPressed: () =>
  Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: inviteLink))
    .then((value) { //only if ->
       ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar)); // -> show a notification
},
```

Comment: no need 3rd party lib, just import `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';` and use `Clipboard `

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library [clipboard_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/clipboard_manager) to do the actual act of storing the text in the clipboard. Then just access the text you want to copy through the `TextEditingController` instance.

```
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Copy'),
  onPressed: () {
    ClipboardManager.copyToClipBoard(
            _textEditingController.value.text)
        .then((result) {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: Text('Copied to Clipboard'),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'Undo',
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      );
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    });
  },
),
```

or access the `String` through a variable

```
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Copy'),
  onPressed: () {
    ClipboardManager.copyToClipBoard(
            _variableContainingString)
        .then((result) {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: Text('Copied to Clipboard'),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'Undo',
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      );
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
    });
  },
),
```