# How to copy text inside container in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

Please, I added a picture below. Here is a container I've created with a button, with an icon and two different texts(one up and one down). Please how do I do it that if I long press on the button the bottom text will be copied to my clipboard, so I can paste it elsewhere on my phone

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter (Dart) How to add copy to clipboard on tap to a app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55885433/flutter-dart-how-to-add-copy-to-clipboard-on-tap-to-a-app)

Answer (score 1):

Import this:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Wrap your button widget with `GestureDetector` and add an anonymous function

```
GestureDetector(
  onLongPress: () {
    Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: yourText));
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text("Text copied to clipboard"),
      ),
    );
  },
  child: // Your button widget
)
```

Edit: I've added code to show a popup that says text copied to clipboard.

Comment: How do I do do that there will be a small pop up that says copied to clipboard after the text is copied

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Put your container widget inside the `GestureDectector` and `onLongPress` you can add function to copy your desired text to clipboard.

```
GestureDetector(
  onLongPress: () {
    Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: yourText));
    Toast.show('Text Copied');
  },
  child: // Your Container
)
```