# How to copy file and directory to clipboard in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

This question [Flutter (Dart) How to add copy to clipboard on tap to a app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55885433/flutter-dart-how-to-add-copy-to-clipboard-on-tap-to-a-app) already tells how to copy a text to clipboard in dart.

Now I would like to copy a file or directory to clipboard. Something like this:

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  String fileOrDirectoryPath = "/some/path/file.txt";
  copyFileOrDirectoryToClipboard(fileOrDirectoryPath);
}
```

Then I would be able to paste the file or directory in my file manager with `Ctrl + V`.

Any idea to achieve this ?

Comment: Not currently possible without writing platform specific code. The flutter [ClipboardData class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/ClipboardData-class.html): `This data structure currently supports only plain text data, in the text property.`

You can write some Windows specific code to PInvoke [SetClipboardData](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetClipboardData.html)

Comment: Of course there is the possibility someone has already written that platform specific code: there is the package [super_clipboard](https://pub.dev/packages/super_clipboard) which seems to offer file support

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [super_clipboard](https://pub.dev/packages/super_clipboard) package which supports all platforms.

```
Directory temp = Directory.systemTemp;
                Directory tempHome = Directory('${temp.path}/home');
                await tempHome.create();
                File file = File('${tempHome.path}/home.dart');

                await file.writeAsString('This is a test');

                final item = DataWriterItem();

                item.add(Formats.fileUri(tempHome.uri));
                await ClipboardWriter.instance.write([item]);
```